# How to improve VectorDensityPlot ColorFuntion resolution?

Tags: plotting, vector

Whenever I use VectorDensityPlot I get presented with extremely poor resolution colour function with cuboid shape:

```
m = CirclePoints [125];
f[p_] := 0.01*((x-p[[1]])/(((x-p[[1]])^2+(y-p[[2]])^2)^(2/2)));
g[p_] := 0.01*((y-p[[2]])/(((x-p[[1]])^2+(y-p[[2]])^2)^(2/2)));
VectorDensityPlot[{Total[Map[f, m]], Total[Map[g, m]]} , {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2,2}, ColorFunction -> (ColorData["Rainbow"][#5]&) , PlotLegends -> BarLegend["Rainbow"], ColorFunctionScaling -> False, VectorRange -> All, VectorPoints -> 50]
```

[image]

How do you make it as good as Lineintegralconvolutionplot (example below) ?

[image]

Comment: Include code for minimally working example of your plot with undesired resolution.

Comment: Have you tried any options, e.g., `MaxRecursion`?

Comment: @BobHanlon increasing it gave me a better result, the default is practically unusable, but I can't go over MaxRecursion 3 without needing the pro version for more computation time. Is there another way around it?

Comment: I don't know what a pro version is.

Comment: @BobHanlon Wolfram cloud https://www.wolfram.com/wolfram-one/pricing/students/

Comment: Use `Evaluate`, i.e., `VectorDensityPlot[Evaluate@{Total[Map[f, m]], Total[Map[g, m]]}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, ColorFunction -> (ColorData["Rainbow"][#5] &), PlotLegends -> BarLegend[ "Rainbow"], ColorFunctionScaling -> False, VectorRange -> All, VectorPoints -> 50, MaxRecursion -> 4]`

Comment: @BobHanlon thanks, I'm assuming that stops it being evaluated multiple times, certainty sped it up

Comment: But why not still using `LineIntegralConvolutionPlot`?

Comment: @LewisKelsey Do you try to visualize electric field of 125 charges on a circle?